# opening a file from database for editing in asp.net mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I need to open a file which is stored in database for editing purpose and it should get saved back in the database when i save the document. For e.g if a word file is stored in the database , I want to open it and edit it and then save again by doing ctrl+s. I know using "File" method I can open it. But how to store the edited file back to the database without having to upload it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use relational database mapper like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), given that you use [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) to store those files.

Then you would simply have attached entities, that will be updated in the database with a single

```
SubmitChanges()
```

call.

Although, I would highly suggest to look into [document-oriented databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am new to MVC alltogether. I dont know much about NHibernate as well. So, is there a possible way to do it traditional asp.net mvc. I will surely see about NHibernate as well.

Comment: You could use Entity Framework as it is an alternative to NHibernate and is already included in MVC template.

Comment: @divydas : Thanks a lot. Will try that and see if I can manage to do which is required.